# Git not ignoring untracked file

Tags: git, gitignore

I sometimes use VSCode, which sometimes results in `.vscode` folders spontaneously appearing. I am fine with this, but I don't want them in my git repositories, so I added them to my global gitignore.

Yet in at least one repository running `git status` still shows an untracked `.vscode` directory. Output from relevant commands follows

```
.config on  canon [?] via ❄️  impure 
❯ gc ~/.config/git/ignore           
.*.swp
result
.vscode/
__pycache__/

.config on  canon [?] via ❄️  impure 
❯ git st                 
On branch canon
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/canon'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    nixpkgs/home-manager/scripts/.vscode/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

`man 5 gitignore` says that ignore patterns will match on any level unless the file has a `/` at the beginning or middle - which this pattern doesn't. Why, then, does the directory show up as untracked in `git status`?

Comment: I don't consider this a duplicate of any other gitignore question I could find, as they dealt with git not ignoring *tracked* files. I'm sure someone will point out a relevant question I missed, tho

Answer (score 0):

Patterns in a repository's own `.gitignore` take precedence over global patterns. If the repository's own `.gitignore` file contains a line that negates a line from `$env:XDG_DATA_HOME/git/ignore`, (in this case the line was `!/nixpkgs/**`) the file will not be ignored.

`git check-ignore` is a useful tool for figuring out why a file is or isn't being ignored.